# How does an sbt plugin get a path to a file in the plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt (0.11.2) plugin that needs to get a path to text files inside the plugin.  How do I do that?  baseDirectory, sourceDirectories etc are set to the base of the project that's including the plugin, not the base of the plugin itself.

I'd like to provide a command to the plugin user that pulls defaults from a ruby file inside the plugin, and then allows the plugin user to override those defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use good old Java's Class.getResource or Class.getResourceAsStream method? E.g. like this:

```
object TestPlugin extends Plugin {

  override def settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    commands += testCommand
  )

  def testCommand = Command.command("test")(action)

  def action(state: State) = {
    try {
      val in = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")
      val text = Source.fromInputStream(in).getLines mkString System.getProperty("line.separator")
      logger(state).info(text)
      in.close()
      state
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger(state).error(e.getMessage)
        state.fail
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that helps.  I really do need a path to the root of the plugin, whether it's a jar or a directory.  Lots of things inside the first file are going to contain many references to other relative paths (it's ruby), so having a stream isn't useful, and copying out the stream also isn't useful.

Comment: What exactly is a path? Wouldn't getClass.getResource help? That returns an URL, e.g. file:/foo/bar.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I misread the doc and thought that the only thing I could do was to get a stream.  I ended up using c.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath.